# Overriding continuation state storage/restore algorithm?

Tags: c#, async-await

When i saw the first news about await, i was very excited and i thought many ways of using it.
One of these is to use it in my web framework to hide the asynchronous aspect of client/server exchanges like it's done in several frameworks. 
So here is the deal:

I would like to write things like that:

```
{   
    Page p = new Page();
    FormResponse response = await p.Show();
    var field1 = reponse.inputField["input1"];
    ...
}
```

I would like the dev to be able to write this code on the server. As you guess `p.Show()` write in the HttpResponse the html code displaying the page with the form, and send the response to the client, so, the thread is 
killed and i never reach the next instruction (`FormResponse response =`).

So here is my question:
Is there any way of doing such a thing ? I know await cut the code, pack it in a continuation, make the closure for us, and store it somewhere to call it back when p.Show() is done.
But here, the thread is going to be killed, and this is my code which recieve the submit response from Page which has to deal with it. So i have to restore the continuation that "await" created and execute it myself.

Am i getting high or is it possible ?

Edit : additional infos

I can explain a bit more, but we need an example. 
Imagine you want to make an async call to a webservice, you just use await and then call the webs. 
A webs doesn't display any page, it returns pieces of information and you can continue the next instructions, so with a webs we have : Client -> Server A [-callwebs-> Server B ->] Server A -> Client.

Now, imagine a webs wich has to display a user interface to grab some information from the user, we can call this kind of webs a UIwebs (a reusable interface called by several webapp),
 it displays the ui, grabs the info, and sends it back to the caller.

So with a UI webs we have : Client -> Server A [-response_redirect-> Client -get-> Server B (here is the UIwebs, the client inputs whatever) -response_redirect-> Client -get-> ] Server A -> Client

What i put between brackets has to be handle in the way by the developper :

so for a classic webs, i can imagine the asynchronous page is "sleeping" waiting the webs to response, but with a UI webs we have to response à redirect to the client, so the page is done for asp.net, and SynchronizationContext says that there is no more async instruction to wait for.

In fact, my need here is the same as turning on the web server, and sending a request to it wich coule restore everything needed to execute the code just after the await.

Regards,
Julien

Answer (score 0):

I'm not sure what the problem is.

If you have, e.g., ASP.NET asynchronous pages, then any top-level (`async void`) function will properly notify ASP.NET that the page is incomplete and release the thread. Later, the continuation will run on a (possibly another) thread, restore the request context, and finish the request.

The `async` design was carefully done to enable this exact behavior. In particular, `async void` increments the outstanding asynchronous operation count in `SynchronizationContext`, as I described [in a recent MSDN article](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/magazine/gg598924.aspx).

If you're running your own host (i.e., not using ASP.NET), then you'll have to implement `SynchronizationContext`. It's non-trivial but not extremely hard, either. Once this is done, `async` and `await` will "just work". :)

**Updated answer in response to edit:**

Keep in mind that `await`/`async` are just syntactical sugar; they don't enable anything that wasn't possible before - they just make it easier.

If I understand your situation correctly, you want a web service to return a UI and then respond to it. This is an inversion of how HTTP works, so you'd have to do some funky stuff with viewstate. I'll think about it...